# Benimm/verhalte dich (gut)

Tags: verb

Welcher Satz ist gebräuchlich?

1. Verhalte dich!
2. Verhalte dich gut!
3. Benimm dich!
4. Benimm dich gut!

Comment: In welcher Situation und mit welcher Bedeutung?

Comment: [Wie stellt man eine gute Frage?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dem [N-Gram nach](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Verhalte+dich%2CVerhalte+dich+gut%2CBenimm+dich%2CBenimm+dich+gut%21&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3#) gibt es nur eine Antwort: "Benimm Dich!"; das entspricht auch meinem Sprachgefühl.

Leider fehlt in der Frage jedweder Kontextbezug, sodass man nur noch feststellen kann, dass in speziellen Kontexten das anders aussehen mag.

Comment: Sie hätten in deutschen Büchern suchen sollen.

Comment: @TeerseifemögenderMr.Kater: Nein! **Sie** hätten in deutschen Büchern suchen sollen, anstatt die Frage hier zu stellen!

Comment: Ich hatte das gemacht, aber die Frage wurde gestellt, weil ich nicht sicher war, ob diese Variante wirklich gebräuchlich ist.